# Buy 1 get 10% discounts for selected products

Tags: magento-1.9, category, shopping-cart-price-rules

How can give buy 1 get 10% for selected products in selected categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can make good use of [Shopping Cart Price Rules](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-shopping-cart.html). You just need to set the criteria on **Conditions** tab. Add a rule, specify **Products Subselection**, then choose **1** on **If total quantity  is**. Then add conditions **under** total quantity and select **SKU** under **Product attribute**. Finally, switch to **Actions**, select **Percent of product price discount** and enter **10** on **Discount Amount**.

Comment: help me @  https://snag.gy/0CRG8I.jpg

Comment: I need to add one extra condition, if 2 qty of the same category then only applied discount. Now the condition is working but, another category of products also getting the discount, i need the same category of products only applicable for this discount.

Comment: Look at Step 3.7 on official document. It can define which product(s) apply the discount.